# Autodesk Viewer raster background

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are looking at using the Forge Viewer for a project to display and markup plans, etc. (for now just 2D, 3D may be added in the future).  Some drawings they may only have in raster formats, i.e. scans of old buildings, etc.

Is there a way to show this raster image at a certain predefined size in the viewer as a background?  Obviously there wouldn't be the ability to snap to anything or get different objects, etc. but it would still be useful when vector data is simply not available.

The only way I can think of is to use design automation to create a CAD file or something and then place the image file there and then convert the CAD file to svf.  That seems very clunky though and I'm not sure it would actually work without testing it.

Is there a better way to display this data in the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no [translation support](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/) for raster images **png, bmp**, etc to generate an **SVF** model out of it.
You could either 
a) use the **image** inside a format that we support (e.g. **DWG** - perhaps place the **image** in it using [Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/)) and translate that to **SVF** 
b) load a dummy model as shown [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/simulate-empty-view-forge-viewer), and then add the **image** using e.g. **threejs** functions